# How to switch display of x & y values on a MATLAB plot, without switching plot() args

Tags: matlab

Consider the following code:

```
x = 0:0.1:pi;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y)
```

I want to switch the display of this plot, such that x displays on the vertical axis and y displays on the horizontal axis.

Obviously for this example, the easiest way is to plot(y,x).  However in my actual code I'd have a ton of plot calls to edit among several functions, and I want to switch back and forth easily. It's a bird's eye East-North plot, and some experiment geometries don't come out very well with East on the x axis.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want is to toggle between views after selecting the axes of you plot. 
For example, say you run your code and have a bunch of plots on the screen. You choose the plot you want to flip by clicking on the empty space within the plot box. Then you type in the command line some function name that is designed to flip the plot. 
This function can be `view` ( `view(90,90)` or `view(0,90)` ), or a generic function such as:

```
function flipplot
    h=get(gca);
    xd=h.Children.XData;
    yd=h.Children.YData;
    h.Children.XData=yd;
    h.Children.YData=xd;
end
```

you can save that flipplot function as flipplot.m, then each time you do the above (select a plot with your mouse etc) and enter`flipplot` on the command line you get what you want.

Comment: This is almost a drop-in fix for my problem.  The trouble is that when I animate my data, the flip is not retained as XData and YData are reassigned...  However, I will use your strategy to bake the flipping ability into my animate code.

Thank you kindly!

Comment: @JohnHaTrick, or may be try one of the `view(90,90)` method instead then, I don't think these `view` statement reassign the `X/YData`.